# NextJS script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I've been trying at this for quite some time now.

On this site I need to be able to place a script tag that will embed a contact form and newsletter sign up form etc to specific pages. So for example on the contact page the contact form script tag will live.

I've tried a bunch of different methods but I'm unable to get the result I'm after for what seems like a pretty basic thing to be able to do.

What I'm finding is initially it seems like it works fine, the script tag works and I see what I expect on the page. But then when you navigate away from the page and go back to it the script tag isn't displaying. It's only when I then refresh the page again will the stuff the script tag is supposed to output appear.

I'm assuming this is happening because with use of the Link tag the website doesn't reload between navigation, instead it all works like a SPA with no reload but it's that refresh that triggers the Script tag to execute.

In my research on this I've seen people recommend not using the Link tag and instead just using a tags so when navigating to the page it has to reload and force the Script tag to display. Only in my case it's not really an option because I am unable to tell which page the client has decided to output a script tag or not because the website is fully dynamic and able to be constructed all via the CMS.

I've tried:

Doing the dangerouslySetInnerHTML trick with the script. Unfortunately the same thing happens as I've described above

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `<script src=""></script>`}}
/>
```

I've also tried using next's built in Script tag https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script with all the different strategy props. Unfortunately the script content either didn't display at all or it acted the same as above.

I've also tried creating a helper function that uses the useEffect to instate the script tag only after navigating to the page, like so:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"


const useScript = (url) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script")

    script.src = url
    script.async = true

    document.body.appendChild(script)

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, [url])
}

export default useScript;
```

and then in the component output to a page:

```
<div>
    {useScript("...")}
</div>
```

This did work! Every time you navigate to the page with the script on it did output the contents of the script tag - not needing a page refresh. The only thing is the contents of the script tag was always output right at the bottom of the page, below the footer and everything. As opposed to where the actual useScript is put in the component.

I tried altering how the useEffect works by making it append the script into an already existing div in the component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"


const useScript = (url) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script")

    script.src = url
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true

    document.getElementById('scriptEx').appendChild(script)

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, [url])
}

export default useScript;
```

But for some reason this doesn't act the same way as the previous setup. On navigation to the page the contents of the script tag don't display again.

The last method I found that does work every single time, but seems like a really ridiculous method to use is putting the script tag inside of an iFrame:

```
<iframe
    srcDoc={`
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <script src="..."></script>
    
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    `}
/>
```

There's got to be a way to do this seemingly simple thing.

If anyone could help it'd be really appreciated!

**Edit**: Here is an example of what I am seeing using Next's Script tag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMumx.png

And here is the jsx that makes up that page:

```
import Script from "next/script";


const example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            The Nav is above this


            <div>
                <p>Container for the form</p>
                <Script src="//basingstokegov.uk.com/resources/sharing/embed.js?sharing=lp-embed&domain=basingstokegov.uk.com&id=3IWH-BN7%2Fthank-you%22" async />
            </div>


            The footer is below this
        </div>
    )
}

export default example
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the child from the element that has the id `scriptEx` as you removed the script from the body. I think that all you have to do is to put

```
    return () => {
      document.getElementById('scriptEx').removeChild(script)
    }
```

instead of

```
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script)
    }
```

**EDIT**

I think because you are using NextJS you need to verify if `document` exists at the top of your `useEffect`. Just like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // If there is no window
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return;
}, [])
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. This works on initial navigation to the page, but then when I navigate away I get a typeerror that says "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')" https://i.imgur.com/BmwsmR5.png

Comment: Ok, sure. I think I updated it. You just need to verify that body exists. I think it's due to NextJS rendering your page on the web. When it does, the window doesn't exist yet. So you can't make use of things like `document.body` nor even `localStorage`.

Comment: Ah thanks @samy-rahmani that has gotten rid of the error. Unfortunately now however, like before, when you navigate away from the page that has the script tag on and navigate back to it the script's contents have disappeared. When I check inside the div with id scriptEx I can see the script tag in there. But nothing displayed

Comment: Hmm. Could you try change the `[url]` to simply `[]` in the `useEffect` function?

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea, unfortunately though the same thing happens. I thought it may be the scripts I'm using but it seems as though any script you use that injects elements onto the page acts in the same way. I tried using Twitter's embed script https://publish.twitter.com/?query=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FInterior%2Fstatus%2F463440424141459456&widget=Tweet and the same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

if you are using NextJs, the solution is very simple. Since v11.0, Next team introduced the **Script component** from the library **next/script**, t's similar to the Head component from the library **next/head**. Basically what you need to do is:

```
import Script from 'next/script'
export default function Home(){
   return(
      <>
         <Script src="#" async />
      </>
   )
}
```

You can read more on the Script component on the Next docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: Awesome this does the trick so that you don't have to refresh the page in order for the contents of the script to display. The only thing is the script is always right at the bottom of the page - below the footer. Is there a way to get it to respect a position and be in the body of a page?

Comment: what do you mean by the script is always right at the bottom of the page.
can you show what this script really do so we can understand why it's showing the content of this script in the wrong position?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing: https://i.imgur.com/4JeiLFO.png

The form just goes right to the bottom of the page instead of in the page body.

I have added the html that makes up the page in the screenshot to my original question

Comment: I get it now, the script is rendering the HTML using the DOM, the script is putting the HTML of the form at the end of the <body>, it's hard coded like that, it will always be at the bottom of your page because all the react app is rendered inside <div id="app"> 
You have 2 options to fix this: either create the form inside of your react app instead of importing a script to do that, or you can edit the source code of the script so it renders inside the react div(I don't suggest this one)

Comment: this doesn't work for me, i would still have to refresh it